# I am getting an error "No source identifer for the attribute "

Tags: android, android-layout

```
No source identifier for the attribute "validatorRegexp"
```

I have recently started working on android application, I want to access the library(which is a project) in my application but the above error is displaying

```
                <ScrollView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:wiget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.extend.example"
                    android:id="@+id/scroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                  <com.extend.wiget.ExtEditText
                            wiget:validate="regexp|numeric|alpha|alphaNumeric|email|creditCard|phone|domainName|ipAddress|webUrl"
                            wiget:validatorRegexp="regexp|empty"
                            wiget:errorString="Custom error message!"
                            wiget:emptyErrorString="Custom empty error message!"
                            wiget:auto="true"
                            android:id="@+id/extEditText11"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Custom validations"
                            android:text="">
                        </com.extend.wiget.ExtEditText>

                </ScrollView>

                Please help me out on this and sorry for the bad english
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it your incorrect spelling of the word `widget` throughout your XML? If you don't get the right namespace and use elements from this incorrect namespace, you will get errors.

Also, it's hard to help without know what library you're using/extending.

Comment: Thnaks for your quick response,

Comment: Thnaks for your quick response,I want to send my source code to you,Could you please send me your mail id, Or suggest me some alternative

Comment: I have resolved this by adding the library in my project, first click on property->android->add libray

Comment: Could any one help me out on resolving Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/extend/editetxtvalidators/Validator;

Comment: @p1234 please answer your own question. Also, you'll have to open a new question to ask about your dex files.

Comment: remove the bin, gen folder and click to clean your project, hope this helps